# acyclic and disjoint union

Tags: approximation

I would like to find a prove of (a) so that the two E are acyclic and disjoint union and I dont unterstand b Could someone shed light on this problem, preferably spiced with some intuition?

Thanks, DarkDragon.[image]

Comment: Please show some respect: post the question in English, instead of a low-resolution image in German. Also, please describe what you've tried.

Comment: A cycle for $(V,\overrightarrow{E})$ would mean that you have a sequence of vertices $v_1,v_2,v_3,...,v_n$ such that $(v_1,v_2),(v_2,v_3),...,(v_{n-1},v_n),(v_n,v_1)\in\overrightarrow{E}$. This means that $v_1<v_2<v_3<...<v_n<v_1$. The transitivity of $<$ would imply that $v_1<v_1$, which contradicts the antisymmetry of $<$. Similarly, reversing inequalities and arrows, you show that $\overleftarrow{E}$ doesn't have cycles.

Comment: If $(u,v)\in\overrightarrow{E}$ and $(u,v)\in \overleftarrow{E}$, then $u<v$ and $u>v$. This is impossible. So, $\overrightarrow{E}$ and $\overleftarrow{E}$ are disjoint. Their union is $E$ because for any two different elements of $u,v$ of $V$ we either have $u<v$ or $u>v$.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the first part by providing a valid topological ordering of the vertices, which shows that the graph is a DAG. To show that the union is equal to $E$ show that each arc in $E$ belongs to one of the two sets

The second part needs more context, what is OPT here?

Comment: optimal solution

Comment: optimal solution of what?