# prove: max (w(E), w(E)) is a 1/2 approximation to the value OPT

Tags: approximation

[image]

Hey I would like to find a answer for b. for a [image] look to the picture that is my answer for it. But I dont habe any Idea how i can solve this. Thank you guys. (I had to translate it to english maybe it will be hard to understand it sorry about that).

Comment: [Link to a related post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/128872/125618).

Comment: I don't know what is the definition of $1/2$-approximation algorithm. Is its definition the following? An algorithm $A$ is a $1/2$ approximation algorithm to the problem $OPT$ if for any instance $I$ of the problem $OPT(I)$ denotes the solution and $A(I)$ the value output by the algorithm and $\max_I\frac{A(I)}{OPT(I)}=\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: yes that is the definition of it thank you for your mention it .

Comment: Or is it $\min_I\frac{A(I)}{OPT(I)}=\frac{1}{2}$, or equivalently $\max_I\frac{OPT(I)}{A(I)}=2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the definition of $1/2$-approximation algorithm, but it looks like what you will need to do is the following argument:

For an enumeration $\sigma:V\to\{1,2,...,n\}$ of the vertices, let, for each input graph $G=(V,E)$, the output of the algorithm be $A_\sigma(G)=\max(w(\overrightarrow{E}),w(\overleftarrow{E}))$.

We have that $OPT(G)\leq w(E)$.

On the other hand,
$$
\begin{align}
A_\sigma(G)&=\max(w(\overrightarrow{E}),w(\overleftarrow{E}))\\
&\geq\frac{w(\overrightarrow{E})+w(\overleftarrow{E})}{2}\\
&= \frac{w(E)}{2}
\end{align}$$
The last equation is because $\overrightarrow{E},\overleftarrow{E}$ is a partition of $E$.

Putting these two inequalities together we get $$OPT(G)\leq w(E)\leq 2A_\sigma(G)$$

Therefore $$\frac{A_\sigma(G)}{OPT(G)}\geq \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: thank you very much I think that is the answer for the problem